# Firebase Phone Auth (Flutter) is not working in some iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I have implemented phone number authentication in a flutter app using firebase phone auth. It is working fine in Android. But it is not working properly in iOS as many users are facing error after they submit sms verification code, though a lot others are using the app just fine. What can be the possible reasons for this scenario? I have submitted my code below.

**Number Submission**

```
void _verifyPhoneNumber() async {

final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
    (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {

  final FirebaseUser user =
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);

  if (user != null) {
    phone = user.phoneNumber;
    fid = user.uid;
    saveLogin(context);
  } else {
    _showErrorDialog("User Verification Error!");
  }
};

final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
    (AuthException authException) {
  _showErrorDialog("Phone Verification Failed");
};

final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
    (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
  _verificationId = verificationId;
  setState(() {
    _title = "Verify SMS Code";
    phoneInput = false;
    phoneSubmit = false;
    codeInput = true;
    codeSubmit = true;
  });
};

final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
    (String verificationId) async {
  _verificationId = verificationId;
  setState(() {
    _title = "Verify SMS Code";
    phoneInput = false;
    phoneSubmit = false;
    codeInput = true;
    codeSubmit = true;
  });
};

await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: "+880" + _mobileNumber,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }
```

**Code Submission**

```
void _signInWithPhoneNumber(String _code) async {

final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
  verificationId: _verificationId,
  smsCode: _code,
);
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
if (user != null) {
  phone = user.phoneNumber;
  fid = user.uid;
  saveLogin(context);
} else {
  _showErrorDialog("User Verification Error!");
}
  }
```

**Plugins Used**

> google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3
>
> firebase_auth: ^0.11.0

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Does your app ask for OTP every time the app is restarted? If that is so then I guess I can tell you the problem

Comment: @AmitKabra After the user logs out or reinstalls app.

Comment: My app is asking for OTP every time the app is restarted on IOS. It does not logs out on Android though once the app is closed. Have you faced a similar issue on IOS?

Comment: No.  I didn't face that.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code for Phone Login and what triggers when you restart your app?

Comment: Could you share AppDelegate.swift ?

Comment: No changes there. Code was added in Futter side.

Comment: I have swizzling disabled and I have made no changes to AppDelegate.swift 
Did you make any changes in general to that for phone auth to work. I am pretty sure I am having problem there. Could you please share AppDelegate.swift?

Comment: We later switched to custom phone auth using sms gateway because of this issue.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. It is working only in some iOS devices. I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue.
I fixed it by following

I copied from firebase:

1. **`REVERSE_CLIENT_ID`** from **`GoogleServices-Info.plist`**
2. **`app bundle id`**
3. **`encoded app id`**

And then,

1. open your XCode
2. choose the `target Runner`
3. go to `info` and click `url types`
4. add all the copied keys ~*one by one*~
5. finally re-run your app and it should work.

**Important**: Make sure to find ***`GoogleServices-Info.plist`*** in *BuildPhased* -> `Compile Sources` if not add the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the REVERSE_CLIENT_ID custom URL schemes to your Xcode project.

According to the firebase documentation:

iOS setup note: App verification may use APNs, if using a simulator (where APNs does not work) or APNs is not setup on the device you are using you must set the URL Schemes to the REVERSE_CLIENT_ID from the GoogleServices-Info.plist file.

How to add custom URL schemes to your Xcode project:

1. Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in the left tree view. Select your app from the TARGETS section, then select the Info tab, and expand the URL Types section.
2. Click the + button, and add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID. To find this value, open the GoogleService-Info.plist configuration file, and look for the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID key. Copy the value of that key, and paste it into the URL Schemes box on the configuration page. Leave the other fields blank.

References from here:

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth