# Phone number verification failed - Flutter (iOS ONLY)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing a OTP phone verification through Firebase Authentication with Flutter. **On Android it works like a charm**, but in the other hand, **on iOS I can't make it work**. This is the error that I'm getting:

*Notice that I'm using OneSignal and it works fine in both on Android and iOS*

> flutter: Phone number verification failed. Code:
>   verifyPhoneNumberError. Message: If app delegate swizzling is
>   disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need
>   to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method.

My flutter doctor:

[image]

My CocoaPods:

[image]

My OPT Function on Flutter:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class SMSFunctions {
  /// Sends the code to the specified phone number.
  static Future<void> sendCodeToPhoneNumber(
      String phoneNo, Function onSuccess, Function onFailed) async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential user) {
      print(
          'Inside _sendCodeToPhoneNumber: signInWithPhoneNumber auto succeeded: $user');
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException authException) {
      print(
          'Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}');
      onFailed();
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      verificationId = verificationId;
      print("code sent to " + phoneNo);
      onSuccess(verificationId);
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      verificationId = verificationId;
      print("time out");
      onFailed();
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNo,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }

  static Future<bool> confirmSMS(String smsCode, String verificationId) async {
    print(smsCode);
    print(verificationId);
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
    AuthResult authResult;
    try {
      authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      print(authResult.user);
      final FirebaseUser currentUser = authResult.user;
      if (currentUser != null)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Plugin Version:

```
firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
```

These are my tries so far:

1. Modified my AppDelegate.swift, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320588/firebase-phone-auth-fails-to-pick-up-on-remote-notifications-registration)

---

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Pass device token to auth
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .prod)

  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
      didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
      fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
      completionHandler(.noData)
      return
    }
    // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
  }

  // For iOS 9+
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,
      options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    if Auth.auth().canHandle(url) {
      return true
    }
    // URL not auth related, developer should handle it.
  }

  // For iOS 8-
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                  open url: URL,
                  sourceApplication: String?,
                  annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    if Auth.auth().canHandle(url) {
      return true
    }
    // URL not auth related, developer should handle it.
  }

  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    for urlContext in URLContexts {
        let url = urlContext.url
        Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
    }
    // URL not auth related, developer should handle it.
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                  didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
    }
    // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
    handleNotification(notification)
  }



}
```

---

2. Tried changing the FirebaseAuth plugin version, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048800/flutter-if-app-delegate-swizzling-is-disabled-remote-notifications-received-by)
3. Changed my URLSCHEMES, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204740/firebase-phone-auth-flutter-is-not-working-in-some-ios-devices)

   My google.services-info.plist (Copied the yellow stripe)
   [image]

   My info.plist URL SCHEMES (Pasted the yellow stripe) //Note that the second item is the Facebook URL SCHEME
   [image: my URLSCHEMES]
4. Changed my FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933387/firebase-cloud-messaging-doesnt-create-push-notifications-but-gets-information)

[image]

5. Configured my Firebase APNs Auth Key and the reCAPTCHA verification, following the [Google Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth)

   [image]

[image]

6. Configured my Signing & Capabilities on Xcode

[image]

Comment: please include relevant codes. don't make us leave this page.

Comment: @vikingosegundo just updated ;)

Comment: and now fix the formatting

Comment: `Return true`this code should not compile.

Comment: @vikingosegundo tried fixing that but it seems that it's ignoring appdelegate.swift when compiling. it doesn't even show up on xcode, i need to open it on another editor

Comment: Well, add it to the project and make sure it has the right target memberships

Comment: I am facing this exact issue. Did you guys manage to solve it? If so then please help me as well

Comment: @AmitKabra not really, I needed get rid of the OTP verification for iOS until I find out how to solve it. If you get to know it, please tell me as well. Thanks

Comment: i also facing exact issue. and couldn’t find any solution till now. please help if anyone could find any working solution

Comment: @sunita didn't find so far, but i will be searching and trying more new solutions if I find any I will post here

Comment: @Vitor I got work around for my problem and I answered below.It could help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact issue and I made some change and it fixed using below code.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseInstanceID

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        }
        return true
  }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

    }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
            print(userInfo)
            return
        }

    }
}
```

**Info.plist**
I added below lines

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

I got reference from the below link.
[https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging][1]

Comment: I'm getting this error while trying to build:
`no module firebase instance id `
do you know what can i do to solve it?

Comment: I tried many many solutions and yours was the only one that helped. Can't thank you enough. I can finally sleep with peace. Thanks a ton and a bit more!!